# Fetch value from JSON using regular expression extractor in JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

Sample JSON body from an http request,

```
[
    {
        "date-range": {
            "high": "2020-09-15",
            "low": "2020-09-13T18:30"
        },
        "visit-identifiers": {
            "system-id": 4,
            "compound-id": "1196_AFG_2_4"
        },
        "study-site": {
            "study": {
                "system-id": 1196,
                "study-protocol-version": "TEST TRIAL 01"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "code": "Asia\/Calcutta",
                "display-name": "(GMT+5:30) Bombay, Calcutta, Madras, Mumbai, New Delhi"
            },
            "organization": {
                "system-id": 8,
                "primary-centre-short-name": "(RNSH) - Kolling Institute of"
            },
            "study-country": {
                "country-code": "AFG",
                "display-name": "Afganasthan"
            },
            "study-site-identifiers": {
                "system-id": 2,
                "long-display-id": "Mr Perf_HYD_ClinPersonnel Test",
                "site-reference": "2",
                "short-display-id": 2
            }
        },
        "defined-activity": {
            "display-name": "NOV-Monitoring",
            "visit-type": "MON"
        },
        "primary-investigator": {
            "title-prefix": "Mr.",
            "system-id": 27,
            "display-name": "Mr. Clinical Mr Perf_HYD_ClinPersonnel Test",
            "voice-telecom-address": "Duplicate 1",
            "title-suffix": "Test",
            "email-telecom-address": "test@test.com",
            "given-name": "Clinical ",
            "middle-name": "",
            "family-name": "Mr Perf_HYD_ClinPersonnel"
        },
        "status": {
            "code": "ON",
            "display-name": "Ongoing"
        }
    },
    {
        "date-range": {
            "high": "2020-06-05",
            "low": "2020-06-05"
        },
        "visit-identifiers": {
            "system-id": 5,
            "compound-id": "1196_AFG_2_5"
        },
        "study-site": {
            "study": {
                "system-id": 1196,
                "study-protocol-version": "TEST TRIAL 01"
            },
            "organization": {
                "system-id": 8,
                "primary-centre-short-name": "(RNSH) - Kolling Institute of"
            },
            "study-country": {
                "country-code": "AFG",
                "display-name": "Afganasthan"
            },
            "study-site-identifiers": {
                "system-id": 2,
                "long-display-id": "DISP_ID_1",
                "site-reference": "2",
                "short-display-id": 2
            }
        },
        "defined-activity": {
            "display-name": "NOV-Monitoring",
            "visit-type": "MON"
        },
        "primary-investigator": {
            "title-prefix": "Mr.",
            "system-id": 27,
            "display-name": "TEST NAME",
            "voice-telecom-address": "Duplicate 1",
            "title-suffix": "Test",
            "email-telecom-address": "test@test.com",
            "given-name": "Clinical ",
            "middle-name": "Test",
            "family-name": "Mr Perf_HYD_ClinPersonnel"
        },
        "status": {
            "code": "PL",
            "display-name": "Planned"
        }
    },
    {
        "date-range": {
            "high": "2020-06-06",
            "low": "2020-06-06"
        },
        "visit-identifiers": {
            "system-id": 6,
            "compound-id": "1196_AFG_2_6"
        },
        "study-site": {
            "study": {
                "system-id": 1196,
                "study-protocol-version": "TEST TRIAL 01"
            },
            "timezone": {
                "code": "Pacific\/Midway",
                "display-name": "(GMT-11:00) Midway Is, Samao"
            },
            "organization": {
                "system-id": 8,
                "primary-centre-short-name": "(RNSH) - Kolling Institute of"
            },
            "study-country": {
                "country-code": "AFG",
                "display-name": "Afganasthan"
            },
           "study-site-identifiers": {
                "system-id": 2,
                "long-display-id": DISP_ID_1",
                "site-reference": "2",
                "short-display-id": 2
            }
        },
        "defined-activity": {
            "display-name": "NOV-Contact Visit",
            "visit-type": "CTT"
        },
        "primary-investigator": {
            "title-prefix": "Mr.",
            "system-id": 27,
            "display-name": "TEST NAME",
            "voice-telecom-address": "Duplicate 1",
            "title-suffix": "Test",
            "email-telecom-address": "test@test.com",
            "given-name": "Clinical ",
            "middle-name": "Test",
            "family-name": "Mr Perf_HYD_ClinPersonnel"
        },
        "status": {
            "code": "PL",
            "display-name": "Planned"
        }
    }
]
```

from the above JSON response data **I want to fetch the compound ID which has status code "PL"**.
In the above JSON have 3 compound id,

```
"compound-id": "1196_AFG_2_4" -- "code": "ON"
"compound-id": "1196_AFG_2_5" -- "code": "PL"
"compound-id": "1196_AFG_2_6" -- "code": "PL"
```

Want to select any one from the above which has status code PL. Currently I am using

```
Regex: "compound-id":"(.+?)"
Template: $1$
match No: 0
```

Is there any way we can put a condition in regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions for parsing JSON is not the best idea, JMeter comes with [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which allows executing arbitrary [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) queries which are more stable, easier to read/maintain and they enable some complex use cases which cannot be implemented with regular expressions.

For particular your use case the relevant expression would be something like:

```
$..[?(@.status.code == 'PL')].visit-identifiers.compound-id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: if I have restriction to use JSO extractor as it is deprecated

Comment: I'm not aware of any deprecation facts or plans for the JSON Extractor, it appeared in [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/your-top-3-questions-about-jmeter-30-%E2%80%93-answered) and it's present in the latest [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) without any signs of being deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space in regex

```
"compound-id": "(.+?)"
```

And if you set [Match No.](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as -1 you will get all the values (a is the variable name):

```
a_1=1196_AFG_2_4
a_2=1196_AFG_2_5
a_3=1196_AFG_2_6
```

> for example when the input variable has the name inputVar, the following variables should have been defined:

> inputVar_1 = wendy
> inputVar_2 = charles
> inputVar_3 = peter
> inputVar_4 = john

You can also use (\w+) instead of space, but then use template $2$ to get the value

Also you can use JSON Extractor to get values as @DimtriT suggested